# Skype for Business on Mac - Disable pop-up notifications

Tags: macos, mac, skype-for-business

I would like to ask if there is a way to disable the pop-up notifications that show up for each message for each user, like in the screenshot below. I am OK with just seeing the badge over the Skype logo in my taskbar

[image]

It is getting very annoying and interruptive...

Thanks for any help - command tools/file edits OK with me ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find it with a tip from another forum - posting here for reference:

Click on the top tool bar Skype for Business

> Preferences->Notifications->Notification Preferences

and then change the Skype for Business alert style to None as the screenshot below. Then when an IM comes in, there will be no pop-up.

[image]